# sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation) value too long for type character varying(80)

Tags: python, database, heroku, sqlalchemy, migrate

I'm trying to migrate my database online using Flask and Heroku. I created a database called userinfo.db and it contains a username and password, the latter of which is hashed for security, so naturally I set the character limit to 80. On my local server I had no issues, but after migrating I got this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation) value too long for type character varying(80)
```

I searched online and it sounds like psychopg is converting it to binary, which is inflating the size of the string. I tried adjusting my database to be TEXT instead of VARCHAR, but what's weird is that after making the change, committing it to github, and even relaunching my website, this error message still appears. This is no longer what my database looks like so why? I've checked and it can't be referring to another database(only this database contains username, password, and an additional nickname field, all of which are referenced in the error message)

This is my first time deploying a website so there's a lot I still don't understand. Here's the important parts of my code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

High likelihood that after you made your changes, Heroku acknowledged the change and restarted the app, however, the DB schema did not get updated. Alembic does not auto-detect type changes in your model.

You'll need to create a script to manually alter your column type.

Comment: How do I do that? It's already being altered in the Python file.

Comment: if you can run a sql command on your database that is what sql does: `ALTER TABLE user ALTER COLUMN password TYPE TEXT;`

Comment: No, I mean I did alter the SQL database, not just the Python file. It still doesn't work.